# Is there a rails plugin that can add emails to a Mailman or DadaMail list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I need to build an application that works like a mailing list. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I thought of using Mailman, DadaMail or GoogleGroups. But I need my Rails app to add and remove emails from these lists.

Any good rails plugins that you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailman includes a bin directory with many utilities that you can call from the command line. For adding email addresses you have:

```
# pwd
/usr/local/mailman

# bin/add_members --help
Add members to a list from the command line.

Usage:
    add_members [options] listname

Options:

    --regular-members-file=file
    -r file
        A file containing addresses of the members to be added, one
        address per line.  This list of people become non-digest
        members.  If file is `-', read addresses from stdin.  Note that
        -n/--non-digest-members-file are deprecated synonyms for this option.

    --digest-members-file=file
    -d file
        Similar to above, but these people become digest members.

    --welcome-msg=<y|n>
    -w <y|n>
        Set whether or not to send the list members a welcome message,
        overriding whatever the list's `send_welcome_msg' setting is.

    --admin-notify=<y|n>
    -a <y|n>
        Set whether or not to send the list administrators a notification on
        the success/failure of these subscriptions, overriding whatever the
        list's `admin_notify_mchanges' setting is.

    --help
    -h  
        Print this help message and exit.

    listname
        The name of the Mailman list you are adding members to.  It must
        already exist.

You must supply at least one of -r and -d options.  At most one of the
files can be `-'.
```

Similarly there is a `remove_members` command. You could call these commands from your Rails app.

Comment: Thanks. That will definitely get me going. I ended up going with DadaMail so I just need to find the equivalent commands.